# Automating VM count in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, command-line-interface

If I run the below script on my EC2 server I get the number of VMs running/stopped in my account:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" | grep InstanceId | wc –l
```

How can I automate this process?
My requirement is the script should run on the VM once daily and send me the output through mail. Please provide me a way to work this out.

Comment: Must it run on the instance? What about using lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need are [Cron Jobs](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux#:%7E:text=The%20Cron%20daemon%20is%20a,other%20commands%20to%20run%20automatically.) to run your script daily.
For the email part, you can achieve it in many ways; I'd recommend using a [library](https://nodemailer.com/about/#:%7E:text=js%20applications%20to%20allow%20easy,is%20licensed%20under%20MIT%20license.) for an easy language, like NodeJS.